# Amazon lex route to amazon connect' chat after not recognizing intent

Tags: amazon-lex, amazon-connect

If we send an intent that is unrecognized by Amazon lex, can we route it to amazon connect chat to talk to an agent? Is it possible?

Fallback intent is available in amazon lex but can we do this is in a lambda function that when fallback intent calls, it routes us to Amazon connect chat